what is the SLURM command to show usage of an account for all of its members?
I tried "sacct -A <allocation_name> ----allusers format=User,JobID,CPUTime,MaxRSS,Elapsed"
Yet, it shows the usage of resources for each job for each user of that account, while I need the cumulative usage for each user of that account.

The command to use is sreport
sreport cluster AccountUtilizationByUser account=<allocation_name>

Bu default, the report period will be the last full day, but you can modify that with parameters start=XXXX-XX-XXand end=XXXX-XX-XX.

Thank you, that gives a much better answer than the sacct command, but it does not show the cumulative usage for some users.

Similar to damienfrancois's answer, the UserUtilizationByAccount option gives a cumulative usage for each user who is a member of an account/allocation:
sreport cluster UserUtilizationByAccount Accounts=<account_name> Start=2024-09-01 End=2024-09-30
